# Deploying an image on ACI giving a python error

Tags: javascript, python, azure, puppeteer, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to deploy an image on ACI. The image contains JS code for opening a URL in a browser. I'm using puppeteer and chromium to achieve this. Locally everything is working fine but when I deploy on ACI, I'm getting the below error in logs.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/container/custom.py", line 912, in _stream_container_events_and_logs
    _stream_logs(container_client, resource_group_name, name, container_name, container_group.restart_policy)
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/container/custom.py", line 866, in _stream_logs
    lines = log.content.split('\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

My guess is that this error has nothing to do with my code. But I'm getting this error every time I deploy, and the browser is also not opening in the container.

I have tried removing my entire code and just printing 'Hello World' in the logs and it works fine but with the entire code it fails. I'm new to Azure and not sure it there is some issue with the deployment or the image.

Comment: Hello, I am able to deploy a sample nginx alpine image using ACI and able to access it on my browser 
https://i.imgur.com/VxkB1YF.png
I checked using your hello-world image as well, and it works. So I believe the issue is not with the ACI, it lies with the code.
Please check your code and see if the container has permission to access the log file.

Comment: Whether your image/code is problematic or not, the error you've shared appears to resemble a logging issue within the Azure CLI. I stumbled upon it when one of my containers crashed.